# Oracle sql get top 3 subquery insert in new table

Tags: sql, oracle

im writing a pretty simple sql program ( In oracle, university forces us to use it for the module). It holds all the stock bought and the amounts paid. Now i want to make a new table that i will enter the top 3 suppliers according to purchases ( so which i purchased the most stock from, bare in mind i can buy multiple products from one suplier) each month. I created this table :

```
CREATE TABLE TOP3SUPP (
Top3_Year number(4) NOT NULL,
Top3_Month number(2) NOT NULL,
Supp_ID number(8) NOT NULL,
Total_Expense number(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT TOP3SUPP_PK PRIMARY KEY (Top3_Year, Top3_Month, Supp_ID));
```

Now i want to enter data from my other table that has all the transactions, i need to find the three top suppliers and enter them into this Top3Supp table, this is my code for that :

```
INSERT INTO TOP3SUPP( Top3_Year, Top3_Month, Supp_ID, Total_Expense)
        VALUES( to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 
       to_char(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 
        (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID FROM (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) AS          total_per_supplier 
                                  FROM FINANCIAL_EXPENSE Where SUPPLIER_ID IS NO T NULL 
                                  Group by SUPPLIER_ID  Order by total_per_supplier desc)
         WHERE  ROWNUM = 1),
         (SELECT total_per_supplier FROM (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) AS total_per_supplier 
                                  FROM FINANCIAL_EXPENSE Where SUPPLIER_ID IS NOT NULL 
                                  Group by SUPPLIER_ID  Order by total_per_supplier desc)
         WHERE  ROWNUM = 1));

       INSERT INTO TOP3SUPP( Top3_Year, Top3_Month, Supp_ID, Total_Expense)
        VALUES( to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 
       to_char(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 
        (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID FROM (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) AS total_per_supplier 
                                  FROM FINANCIAL_EXPENSE Where SUPPLIER_ID IS NOT NULL 
                                  Group by SUPPLIER_ID  Order by total_per_supplier desc)
         WHERE  ROWNUM = 2)
         ,(SELECT total_per_supplier FROM (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) AS total_per_supplier 
                                  FROM FINANCIAL_EXPENSE Where SUPPLIER_ID IS NOT NULL 
                                  Group by SUPPLIER_ID  Order by total_per_supplier desc)
         WHERE  ROWNUM = 2));      

       INSERT INTO TOP3SUPP( Top3_Year, Top3_Month, Supp_ID, Total_Expense)
        VALUES( to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 
       to_char(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 
        (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID FROM (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) AS total_per_supplier 
                                  FROM FINANCIAL_EXPENSE Where SUPPLIER_ID IS NOT NULL 
                                  Group by SUPPLIER_ID  Order by total_per_supplier desc)
         WHERE  ROWNUM = 3)
         ,(SELECT total_per_supplier FROM (SELECT SUPPLIER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) AS total_per_supplier 
                                  FROM FINANCIAL_EXPENSE Where SUPPLIER_ID IS NOT NULL 
                                  Group by SUPPLIER_ID  Order by total_per_supplier desc)
         WHERE  ROWNUM = 3));
```

It looks like a lot of code but i just wanted to give the whole picture. I use group by to find the total ammounts for all the items purchased from one supplier then order them and my plan is to choose the 1st row then the second then the 3rd. In theory ( in my mind) it should work but it only enters the first row, at `ROWNUM = 2` it returns null, I have no idea why and so im asking if someone could give me advice please, and if there is a better way of doing this im all ears!

Extra part :

Like i said i have to get all the previous months top three suppliers too before i can only use the current month sql ( provided by Imagine)

My table looks like this, i have to group together the suppliers each month and get the top 3 suppliers for that month and enter it ... is something like this possible ?

Here is the table i collect my information from :

```
  CREATE TABLE "HR"."FINANCIAL_EXPENSE" 
  ( "TRANS_ID" NUMBER(8,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"PRODUCT_ID" NUMBER(8,0), 
"PRICE" NUMBER(19,4), 
"DATEOFTRANS" DATE, 
"QUANTITY" NUMBER(6,0), 
"TOTAL" NUMBER(19,4) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"SUPPLIER_ID" NUMBER(8,0), 
"TYPE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "FINANCIAL_EXPENSE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("TRANS_ID"));
```

Just say if you need more information or dont understand what im doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one for current date (SYSDATE):

```
-- INSERT INTO TOP3SUPP( Top3_Year, Top3_Month, Supp_ID, Total_Expense)
select 
  to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), to_char(SYSDATE, 'MM'), 
  SUPPLIER_ID, total_per_supplier 
from (
  SELECT SUPPLIER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) AS total_per_supplier
  FROM FINANCIAL_EXPENSE Where SUPPLIER_ID IS NOT NULL 
  Group by SUPPLIER_ID  
  Order by total_per_supplier desc
)
where rownum <=3
```

This is solution for custom month:

```
-- INSERT INTO TOP3SUPP( Top3_Year, Top3_Month, Supp_ID, Total_Expense)
select to_char(cm,'YYYY') custom_year, to_char(cm,'MM') custom_month, SUPPLIER_ID, total_per_supplier 
from (
  SELECT ml.cm, f.SUPPLIER_ID, SUM(f.TOTAL) AS total_per_supplier
  FROM FINANCIAL_EXPENSE f, (
       select to_date('2015-08' /* the custom month */,'YYYY-MM') cm from dual 
  ) ml
  Where 
    f.SUPPLIER_ID IS NOT NULL 
    and f.dateoftrans < last_day(ml.cm)+1 -- to use index on dateoftrans and include last second of month
  Group by ml.cm, f.SUPPLIER_ID  
  Order by total_per_supplier desc
)
where rownum <=3
```

ROWNUM is a pseudocolumn that will be assigned the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 
A ROWNUM value is assigned to a row after it passes the predicate phase of the query but before the query does any sorting or aggregation.
So, if you want to sort data then you should do it inside subquery and after that assign a ROWNUM.
This example shows how it works:

```
select f2.*, rownum rn2 from (
  select f.*, rownum rn1 
  from financial_expense f 
  order by total desc
) f2
where rownum <=3
```

Comment: this is a proof that this sql is the best solution ;)

Comment: It worked thanx alot ! if u dont mind can u pls just explain in short how this statement know how to insert 3 times ? what exaclty does the rownum <=3 mean ?

Comment: I've completed my answer. Do you understand now?

Comment: Im sorry but can i ask you another question about it ? this code is to import the current months data hence the SYSdate use when entering the date. But now before i can do that i have to run the code to enter all the previous months top 3 also ... for example the bussines has been up and running since february but i only installed this system september so i have to get the top 3 suppliers for months February to August then i can run the code u gave me ... any idea how to approach it ? il explain more in the question

Comment: 12c allows a more conventional row limiting clause than the "rownum < ?" of previous versions.

Comment: What about my solution for a custom month?

Comment: It worked like a charm ! thanks alot imagine ... you saved me ! cheers mate let me know when youre in south africa then ill buy you a beer ! ;)

Comment: best regards from Poland :)

Comment: Sorry just noticed it though, it only loads the previous month not more than one month back, so it only get top three from august , it ignores the data from July          EDIT : i see i have to manually input it :)

Comment: I checked it, works fine for me:
for 09-2015 it loads data from month 09, 08, 07....
for 08-2015 it loads data from month 08, 07, 06....
please check it one more time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to try this right now, but I think an approach like this is quite easier:

```
INSERT INTO TOP3SUPP( Top3_Year, Top3_Month, Supp_ID, Total_Expense)
SELECT to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 
       to_char(SYSDATE, 'MM'),
       SUPPLIER_ID, 
       total_per_supplier
FROM 
(
SELECT SUPPLIER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) AS total_per_supplier
FROM FINANCIAL_EXPENSE 
Where SUPPLIER_ID IS NOT NULL 
Group by SUPPLIER_ID  
Order by total_per_supplier desc
) Where ROWNUM <= 3
```

Comment: ORA-00979: "ROWNUM As TOPNUMBER" is not a GROUP BY expression

Comment: Yeah, made a mistake, the SQL sent by @imagine is the correct one. But you get the idea. I corrected it just in case :)